# Designing data structures for a child-first lazy evaluator which prints procedure

Tags: rust, lazy-evaluation

I'm building a lazy expression evaluator [like Python's](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html#asserting-with-the-assert-statement) using a compiler plugin.

I want to print a log like:

```
assert ( left == vec![1, 2, 3, 4] )
assert ( vec![1, 2, 3, 4] == vec![1, 2, 3, 4] );
```

and tried:

```
// crate rt
pub struct Expr<T, F: FnMut() -> T> {
    // I noticed that this must be changed to fn with format!() call, to
    // support updating child.
    src: &'static str, // holds value
}
pub trait EvalTo: Display {
    /// Type of expression
    type Type;

    /// Returns Some(val) when done
    /// Accepts &mut self as it might be called many time.
    fn eval_one_level(&mut self) -> Some<T>;
}

impl<T, F> EvalTo for Expr<T, F> {
    type Type = T;
}
/// Prints source before evaluation, (it must be changed)
/// and value after evaluation.
impl<T, F> Display for Expr<T, F> {}
```

with compiler plugin to create them on compile time. But when I do

```
let left = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
lazy_expr!(left == vec![1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

It expands to

```
::rt::binary({
   ::rt::Expr::wrap(::rt::Source{ expr: "left" }, || Some(left))
}, { 
   ::rt::Expr::wrap(::rt::Source{ expr: "vec!(1, 2, 3, 4)" },
   || vec![1, 2, 3, 4])
}).eq()
```

and the compiler doesn't like it. It says `` cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `FnMut` closure ``.

So I can't use `FnMut`, but it needs to be called multiple time, and needs to be able to modify the child expression.

Is there a data structure which allows capturing local variable, but can called multiple times with `&mut self`? Should I use `FnOnce(&mut Context)`?

Comment: Please produce a [MCVE]. It's very unlikely that someone is going to also create a compiler plugin just to try to reproduce your error. Ideally, make something that can [run on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/). Even better, [review the **7 other questions with the same error message**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cannot+move+out+of+captured+outer+variable+in+an+FnMut+closure+is%3Aq) *before* asking. Then, explain why *this question* is different from *those questions*.

Comment: I decided to do something like http://pybites.blogspot.kr/2011/07/behind-scenes-of-pytests-new-assertion.html because I can't represent ast with generic and this question becomes useless to me.

Comment: @Shepmaster This is question about designing, and those questions are about using FnMut. I'm not trying to move value to closure. Instead, I wanted to do something like allowing both FnOnce and FnMut. And I found that this can be done via [futures-rs](http://alexcrichton.com/futures-rs/futures/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't need this anymore, because I used another apporach. But just to be complete, you can define a trait with `(&mut self)` and use 
[`std::mem::replace`][] to get owned value, and `Option` has a helper method named `.take()`.

For who wants to build lazy evaluatable engine with compiler plugin, I [did some more on compile time](https://github.com/kdy1997/must/blob/52492d76bcd4c852e7dfb5aa8ed89f80598a82f8/must-assert/src/expand/mod.rs#L119-L160).

It calls

```
fn capture<T :?Sized>(&mut self, expr: &'static str, val: &T)
```

from generated code like

```
ctx.capture("f()", &_var_of_expr)
```

so context can write expression and value with it.